# Google Calendar API and JS Promises

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to write my first native JS promise with a Google Calendar API. I've stripped down the JavaScript quick starter code for the Google Calendar API and have it returning to me an array of 10 objects as "events" from my Calendar.

I'm trying to, in vanilla JS, make that API call a promise and then, when it is resolved, do something with the data (for simplicity I'm just trying to console.log it).

Here is the basic G-Calendar API call code.

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'SUPER_SECRET_ID_GOES_HERE';
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    loadCalendarApi();
  }
}

function loadCalendarApi() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
}

function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
    'showDeleted': false,
    'singleEvents': true,
    'maxResults': 10,
    'orderBy': 'startTime'
  });

  request.execute(function(resp) {
    var events = resp.items;
    // console.log(events)
    // return( events )
    // these are the event objects I want my promise to 
  })
}
```

Now I know that the basic structure of a native JS promise looks something like this...

```
function testPromise() {

  var p1 = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        //Google-Calendar-API-Call Goes Here 
    }
  );

  p1.then(
    function(val) {
      console.log(val)
    })
  .catch(
    function(reason) {
      console.log('Handle rejected promise (' + reason + ') here.');
    });
}
```

I've tried some different ways of calling resolve(loadCalendarApi) and/or resolve(listUpcomingEvents), but haven't gotten anything to console log.

What am I doing wrong, and how should I be properly using my promise with the Google-Calendar API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  //List upcoming events will return a new Promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var events = resp.items;

      //After the request is executed, you will invoke the resolve function with the result as a parameter.
      resolve(events);
    })
  });
}
```

When you call **listUpcomingEvents** you must return a new promise, this will represent an operation that hasn't been completed yet; when you invoke either resolve or reject, this operation will be completed and it will continue with either **then** if it was resolved or **catch** if it was rejected.

Invoking **listUpcompingEvents** would look something like this:

```
listUpcomingEvents().then(function(events){
  //Whatever goes after
}).catch(function(err){
  //What happens if the promise was rejected
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Rene! Thanks for the answer. Your code helped me out a lot.        
The promise you wrote works perfectly. To get it to work properly I also had to change the `loadCalendarApi` function. It currently uses the promise as like so:        

    

`var loadCalendarApi = function() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    listUpcomingEvents().then(function(events) {
      console.log(events)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("ERROR", err)
    });
  });
}`